# Pandas.DataFrame slicing with multiple date ranges

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a datetime-indexed dataframe object with 100,000+ rows. I was wondering if there was a convenient way using pandas to get a subset of this dataframe that is within multiple date ranges.

For example, let us say that we have two date ranges:

`(datetime.datetime(2016,6,27,0,0,0), datetime.datetime(2016,6,27,5,0,0)`

and

`(datetime.datetime(2016,6,27,15,0,0), datetime.datetime(2016,6,27,23,59,59)`

Let us say we want to get all rows of a dataframe object that is in either the first date range or the second date range, where the dataframe object has rows for every second from `2016-06-27 00:00:00` to `2016-06-27 23:59:59`. Is there an easy way in pandas to do this?

Answer (score 8):

There are [two main ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370182/190597) to slice a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex by date.

- by slices: `df.loc[start:end]`. If there are multiple date ranges, the single
  slices may be concatenated with `pd.concat`.
- by boolean selection mask: `df.loc[mask]`

---

**Using pd.concat and slices**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 10**2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 2)), 
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-6-27', periods=N, freq='45T'))

result = pd.concat([df.loc['2016-6-27':'2016-6-27 5:00'],
                    df.loc['2016-6-27 15:00':'2016-6-27 23:59:59']])
```

yields

```
                     0  1
2016-06-27 00:00:00  0  2
2016-06-27 00:45:00  5  5
2016-06-27 01:30:00  9  6
2016-06-27 02:15:00  8  4
2016-06-27 03:00:00  5  0
2016-06-27 03:45:00  4  8
2016-06-27 04:30:00  7  0
2016-06-27 15:00:00  2  5
2016-06-27 15:45:00  6  7
2016-06-27 16:30:00  6  8
2016-06-27 17:15:00  5  1
2016-06-27 18:00:00  2  9
2016-06-27 18:45:00  9  1
2016-06-27 19:30:00  9  7
2016-06-27 20:15:00  3  6
2016-06-27 21:00:00  3  5
2016-06-27 21:45:00  0  8
2016-06-27 22:30:00  5  6
2016-06-27 23:15:00  0  8
```

---

Note that unlike most slicing syntaxes used in Python,

```
df.loc['2016-6-27':'2016-6-27 5:00']
```

is inclusive on both ends -- the slice defines a closed interval, is not a
half-open interval.

---

**Using a boolean selection mask:**

```
mask = (((df.index >= '2016-6-27') & (df.index <= '2016-6-27 5:00')) 
        | ((df.index >= '2016-6-27 15:00') & (df.index < '2016-6-28')))
result2 = df.loc[mask]
assert result.equals(result2)
```

Comment: Hi @unutbu could you please consider this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532543/how-to-slice-rows-in-between-time-intervals-on-a-case-by-case-basis-python Thanks!

Comment: What if we had multiple date ranges and not just two?

Answer (score 7):

I feel the best option will be to use the direct checks rather than using loc function:

```
df = df[((df.index >= '2016-6-27') & (df.index <= '2016-6-27 5:00')) 
    | ((df.index >= '2016-6-27 15:00') & (df.index < '2016-6-28'))]
```

It works for me.

Major issue with loc function with a slice is that the limits should be present in the actual values, if not this will result in KeyError.