# How to slice rows in between time intervals on a case by case basis python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to slice rows in `df1` in between time intervals `StartTime` and `EndTime` in **`df2`** on a case by case basis(by values in column `Group_Id` in **`df2`**). Then concatenate the multiple slices together given they are of the same formats.

So this is `df1`:

```
      Timestamp           Group_Id      Data
2013-10-20 00:00:05.143    11           14
2013-10-21 00:05:10.377    11           15
2013-10-22 14:22:15.501    11           19
                   ...
2019-02-05 00:00:05.743    101          21
2019-02-10 00:00:10.407    101          33
```

and `df2`:

```
EndTime          StartTime             Group_Id
27/10/13 16:08   20/10/13 16:08          11
03/12/16 16:11   26/11/16 16:11          2
24/10/14 12:08   17/10/14 12:08          11
04/07/17 08:00   27/06/17 08:00          100
03/04/13 14:10   27/03/13 14:10          26
15/11/18 17:00   08/11/18 17:00          46
11/02/19 00:20   04/02/19 00:20          101
```

Step1: 
We start from first row in column `Group_Id`,`df2`: 11

Step2:
Copy & Paste corresponding rows in **`df1`** that lie between `EndTime` & `StartTime` for `Group_Id==11`

Step3: 
Concat all sliced subsets from each **row** in `Group_Id`(`df2`)

Hopefully final dataset `df3` looks like this:

```
Group_Id EndTime         StartTime      Timestamp                 Data
11       27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13 16:08 2013-10-20 20:00:05.143   14
11       27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13 16:08 2013-10-21 00:05:10.377   15
11       27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13 16:08 2013-10-22 14:22:15.501   19
                             ...
101      11/02/19 00:20  04/02/19 00:20 2019-02-05 00:00:05.743   21
101      11/02/19 00:20  04/02/19 00:20 2019-02-10 00:00:10.407   33
                             ...
```

A bad Pseudo code:

```
for i in df2['Group_Id']:
  if i = df1['Group_Id'],
  dfxx = df1[(df1['Timestamp'] <= df2.loc[i, 'EndTime']) & df1['Timestamp'] > (df2.loc['EndTime'] - dt.timedelta(days=7)])                                                                   
  pd.concat(dfxx for all i)
  i = i+1
```

Hope this helps to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: `df1.Timestamp`   `2013-10-20 00:00:05.143` is outside of `27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13  16:08`. Why is it in the output?

Comment: @Andy L. thanks that's a typo I just fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `df1.Timestamp` to datetime. Merge on `Group_Id`. Create `IntervalIndex` from `start` and `end` of `df3`. Use listcomp to create True/False mask `m` and slice `df3`.

```
df1.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df1.Timestamp)
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='Group_Id')
iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([*df3[['StartTime','EndTime']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True).to_records(index=False)], 
                                   closed='both')
m = [x in iix[i] for i, x in enumerate(df3.Timestamp)]

df3.loc[m]

Out[494]:
          EndTime       StartTime  Group_Id               Timestamp  Data
0  27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13 16:08        11 2013-10-20 20:00:05.143    14
1  27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13 16:08        11 2013-10-21 00:05:10.377    15
2  27/10/13 16:08  20/10/13 16:08        11 2013-10-22 14:22:15.501    19
6  11/02/19 00:20  04/02/19 00:20       101 2019-02-05 00:00:05.743    21
7  11/02/19 00:20  04/02/19 00:20       101 2019-02-10 00:00:10.407    33
```

Comment: thank you but I don't know why the output is empty with only headings

Comment: @nilsinelabore: there is something unusual in your real dataset which is not in the sample data you provided. You may do line-by-line command above and check the result of each line to see where it fails on your real dataset.

Comment: thanks I can run it now but it seems `Timestamp` is not filtered by the `StartTime ` and `EndTime `

Comment: @nilsinelabore: after creating `iix` on your real dataset, check it to see whether it is dtype `IntervalIndex` with values from `df3.StartTime`, `df3.EndTime` (note: `df3` is the result from `merge`) and check `df1.Timestamp` is dtype `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a merge based on your example.

```
df1.merge(df2,on='Group_Id',how='left')
```

Comment: thanks I don't think it'll work as `Group_Id` is not unique..