# How to select a range of values in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, range

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = 'filename.csv'
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df 

        one       two     three  four   five
a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  bar   True
b  0.932424  1.224234  7.823421  bar  False
c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  bar  False
d  0.232424  2.342112  0.982342  unbar True
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  bar   True
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bar  False
```

I would like to select a range for a certain column, let's say column `two`. I would like to select all values between -0.5 and +0.5. How does one do this?

I expected to use

```
-0.5 < df["two"] < 0.5
```

But this (naturally) gives a ValueError:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried

```
-0.5 (< df["two"] < 0.5)
```

But this outputs all `True`.

The correct output should be

```
0    True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    True
```

What is the correct way to find a range of values in a pandas dataframe column?

EDIT: Question

Using `.between()` with

```
df['two'].between(-0.5, 0.5, inclusive=False)
```

would would be the difference between

```
 -0.5 < df['two'] < 0.5
```

and inequalities like

```
 -0.5 =< df['two'] < 0.5
```

?

Comment: There is a better alternative: `df.query('-0.5 <= two < 0.5')`

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for this! I hadn't thought of this. This is very clean

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=False` for strict inequalities:

```
df['two'].between(-0.5, 0.5, inclusive=False)
```

The `inclusive` parameter determines if the endpoints are included or not (`True`: `<=`, `False`: `<`).  This applies to both signs. If you want mixed inequalities, you'll need to code them explicitly:

```
(df['two'] >= -0.5) & (df['two'] < 0.5)
```

Comment: What do you mean by using `inclusive=False` for strict inequalities? I'm not sure I understand the difference between `inclusive=True` and `inclusive=False`?

Comment: Using `between(-0.5, 0.5)` , what would be the difference between `-0.5 < value < 0.5` and `-0.5 =
< value < 0.5` ?

Comment: NB: The parenthesis in the second expression are important.

Comment: will it works for date also ?
 'df['date'].between(2010-03-01, 2010-05-01, inclusive=False)' 
I found the sol https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370182/8927035

Answer (score 17):

`.between` is a good solution, but if you want finer control use this:

```
(0.5 <= df['two']) & (df['two'] < 0.5)
```

The operator `&` is different from `and`. The other operators are `|` for `or`, `~` for `not`. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas) for more info.

Your statement was the same as this:

```
(0.5 <= df['two']) and (df['two'] < 0.5)
```

Hence it raised the error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why the `ValueError` was raised!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would get the values within the range without using between().

```
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
df2["two"][(df2["two"] >= -.5) & (df2["two"] <= .5)]
```