# Pandas: Selecting DataFrame rows between two dates (Datetime Index)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex and one column `MSE Loss`
the index is formatted as follows:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-16 07:14:41', '2015-07-16 07:14:48',
           '2015-07-16 07:14:54', '2015-07-16 07:15:01',
           '2015-07-16 07:15:07', '2015-07-16 07:15:14',...]
```

It includes several days.

I want to select all the rows (all times) of a particular days without specifically knowing the actual time intervals. 
For example: Between `2015-07-16 07:00:00` and `2015-07-16 23:00:00`

I tried the approach outlined here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

But `df[date_from:date_to]`

outputs:

```
KeyError: Timestamp('2015-07-16 07:00:00')
```

So it wants exact indices. Furthermore, I don't have a `date`column. Only an index with the dates.

What is the best way to select a whole day by just providing a date `2015-07-16` and then how could I select a specific time range within a particular day?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Option 1**:

Sample df:

```
df
                      a
2015-07-16 07:14:41  12
2015-07-16 07:14:48  34
2015-07-16 07:14:54  65
2015-07-16 07:15:01  34
2015-07-16 07:15:07  23
2015-07-16 07:15:14   1
```

It looks like you're trying this without `.loc` (won't work without it):

```
df.loc['2015-07-16 07:00:00':'2015-07-16 23:00:00']
                      a
2015-07-16 07:14:41  12
2015-07-16 07:14:48  34
2015-07-16 07:14:54  65
2015-07-16 07:15:01  34
2015-07-16 07:15:07  23
2015-07-16 07:15:14   1
```

**Option 2**:

You can use boolean indexing on the index:

```
df[(df.index.get_level_values(0) >= '2015-07-16 07:00:00') & (df.index.get_level_values(0) <= '2015-07-16 23:00:00')]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `truncate`:

```
begin = pd.Timestamp('2015-07-16 07:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2015-07-16 23:00:00')

df.truncate(before=begin, after=end)
```

Comment: Using truncate requires a sorted datetime index

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [panda function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) `between_time`.

```
the_timed_df=df["my_time_column"].between_time(date_from,date_to)
```

Should do what you want if I did not mess some detail up :-)

Comment: I think this only works with times, so it would have to be `between_time(time_from, time_to)`.