# split the date range into multiple ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime

I have data in CSV like this:

```
1940-10-01,somevalue
1940-11-02,somevalue
1940-11-03,somevalue
1940-11-04,somevalue
1940-12-05,somevalue
1940-12-06,somevalue
1941-01-07,somevalue
1941-02-08,somevalue
1941-03-09,somevalue
1941-05-01,somevalue
1941-06-02,somevalue
1941-07-03,somevalue
1941-10-04,somevalue
1941-12-05,somevalue
1941-12-06,somevalue
1942-01-07,somevalue
1942-02-08,somevalue
1942-03-09,somevalue
```

I want to separate the dates from `1-oct-year` to `31-march-next-year` for all data. So for data above output will be:

**1940/1941:**

```
1940-11-02,somevalue
1940-11-03,somevalue
1940-11-04,somevalue
1940-12-05,somevalue
1940-12-06,somevalue
1941-01-07,somevalue
1941-02-08,somevalue
1941-03-09,somevalue
```

**1941/1942:**

```
1941-10-04,somevalue
1941-12-05,somevalue
1941-12-06,somevalue
1942-01-07,somevalue
1942-02-08,somevalue
1942-03-09,somevalue
1942-10-01,somevalue
```

My code trails are:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))

quaters = []
year =  datetime.strptime(data[0][0], '%Y-%m-%d').year
for each in data:
    date =  datetime.strptime(each[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
    print(each)        

    if (date>=datetime(year=date.year,month=10,day=1) and date<=datetime(year=date.year+1,month=3,day=31)):
        middle_quaters[-1].append(each)
    if year != date.year:            
        quaters.append([])
```

But I am not getting expected output. I want to store each range of dates in separate list.

Comment: isn't your sample result have error? Why result for 1941/42 has a record from year 1940? See my answer with correct outputs.

Comment: @Kaushal28 i justed noticed it, it was typo.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pandas dataframe` to do this.. 
it would be easier.. 
follow this
[Pandas: Selecting DataFrame rows between two dates (Datetime Index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547401/pandas-selecting-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates-datetime-index?rq=1)

so for your case

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.loc[startDate : endDate]



# you can walk through a bunch of ranges like so..
listOfDateRanges = [(), (), ()]
for date_range in listOfDateRanges:
   df.loc[date_range[0] : date_range[1]]
```

Comment: but my date range is changing like it can lie in any year, so i cant hardcode it

Comment: where are you hardcoding the values?

Comment: your startDate and endDate can be anything you want.. 
have them in a list.. as a tuple.. and walk through the range to get the required dates..

Comment: @Kaushal28 what do you mean? Its basically a filtered argument you are passing..

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use `pandas` library. Here is the sample code for the same:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('so.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])   #timestamp is your time column
current_year, next_year = 1940, 1941
df = df.query(f'(timestamp >= "{current_year}-10-01") & (timestamp <= "{next_year}-03-31")')
print (df)
```

This gives following result on your data:

```
   timestamp      value
0 1940-10-01  somevalue
1 1940-11-02  somevalue
2 1940-11-03  somevalue
3 1940-11-04  somevalue
4 1940-12-05  somevalue
5 1940-12-06  somevalue
6 1941-01-07  somevalue
7 1941-02-08  somevalue
8 1941-03-09  somevalue
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Without external packages... create a lookup based on the field of choice, and then make an int of it and do a less that vs greater than to establish the range.

```
import re

data = '''1940-10-01,somevalue
1940-11-02,somevalue
1940-11-03,somevalue
1940-11-04,somevalue
1940-12-05,somevalue
1940-12-06,somevalue
1941-01-07,somevalue
1941-02-08,somevalue
1941-03-09,somevalue
1941-05-01,somevalue
1941-06-02,somevalue
1941-07-03,somevalue
1941-10-04,somevalue
1941-12-05,somevalue
1941-12-06,somevalue
1942-01-07,somevalue
1942-02-08,somevalue
1942-03-09,somevalue'''

lookup={}
lines = data.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    d = re.sub(r'-','',line.split(',')[0])
    lookup[d]=line

dates=sorted(lookup.keys())

_in=19401201
out=19411004
outfile=[]
for date in dates:
    if int(date) > _in and int(date) < out:
        outfile.append(lookup[date])

for l in outfile:
    print outfile
```

Comment: What is the input is stored in file? This won't be optimised approach to first converting `csv` to string and then apply integer operations to determine date time ranges.