# Select rows between two DatetimeIndex dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, datetimeindex

I have a CSV file of the following format:

```
vm,time,LoadInt1
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:00:00,3.133333
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:05:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:10:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:15:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:20:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:25:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:30:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:35:00,0.000000
abc-webapp-02,2017-05-31 10:40:00,0.000000
```

I read the CSV file into a DataFrame using the following code. The date is parsed as index (DatetimeIndex)

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", header=0, parse_dates=[1], index_col=1, date_parser=dateparse)
```

Now I am trying to get all the rows between two dates using the following code (The real CSV file has large number of rows between the dates mentioned below):

```
df.loc['2017-05-30' : '2017-05-31']
```

**Please note, above approach is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates). But, it's not working for me. So, it may not be a duplicate question.**

Comment: Can you show the output of `df.head()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `query` method:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", index_col=1, parse_dates=True)

In [121]: df.query("'2017-05-30' <= index <= '2017-06-01'")
Out[121]:
                                vm  LoadInt1
time
2017-05-31 10:00:00  abc-webapp-02  3.133333
2017-05-31 10:05:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:10:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:15:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:20:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:25:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:30:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:35:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
2017-05-31 10:40:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I was wondering why loc is not working.

Answer (score 2):

- This type of index slicing includes the end points and so what you have will include the entire sample set

  ```
  df.loc['2017-05-30':'2017-05-31']
  #df['2017-05-30':'2017-05-31']

                                  vm  LoadInt1
  time                                        
  2017-05-31 10:00:00  abc-webapp-02  3.133333
  2017-05-31 10:05:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:10:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:15:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:20:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:25:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:30:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:35:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  2017-05-31 10:40:00  abc-webapp-02  0.000000
  ```
- This shows the same thing but actually subsets

  ```
  df.loc['2017-05-31 10:10':'2017-05-31 10:35']

                                  vm  LoadInt1
  time                                        
  2017-05-31 10:10:00  abc-webapp-02       0.0
  2017-05-31 10:15:00  abc-webapp-02       0.0
  2017-05-31 10:20:00  abc-webapp-02       0.0
  2017-05-31 10:25:00  abc-webapp-02       0.0
  2017-05-31 10:30:00  abc-webapp-02       0.0
  2017-05-31 10:35:00  abc-webapp-02       0.0
  ```
- Your import could be made smaller.  You don't need the parser

  ```
  df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", parse_dates=[1], index_col=1)
  ```

Comment: The problem is df.loc['2017-05-30':'2017-05-31'] is not working for me. That is surprising me. It's returning an empty series. That is true when I don't have the parser as well. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Are you still using the same import you used.  I used the one I mentioned and the index is a `DatetimeIndex`.  Check to see yours is too. `type(df.index)`  If it isn't then that means your conversion to datetime didn't work and.  Try mine instead, which I posted in my third bullet.  What version of pandas are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: The index is : pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex. And the pandas version is 0.18.1. Even after removing 'dateparse' thing, I am getting the same empty result. :-(

Comment: @ArnabBiswas take off the `loc` and just do `df['2017-05-30':'2017-05-31']`

Comment: Noop. It's not working. One catch is in my CSV, the time indices are not equally spaced. For example, for the latest date, every 5 minutes, there is one data point. For one day older data, every half an hour there is a data point. The older is the data, more sparse it is. Could that be a reason?