# What is the most efficient way to count the number of instances occurring within a time frame in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, list-comparison

I am trying to run a simple count function which runs a dataframe of event times (specifically surgeries) against another dataframe of shift time frames, and returns a list of how many events occur during each shift. These csvs are thousands of rows, though, so while the way I have it set up currently works, it takes forever. This is what I have:

```
numSurgeries = [0 for shift in range(len(df.Date))]

for i in range(len(OR['PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM'])):
    for shift in range(len(df.DateTime)):
        if OR['PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM'][i] >= df.DateTime[shift] and OR['PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM'][i] < df.DateTime[shift+1]:
            numSurgeries[shift] += 1
```

So it loops through each event and checks to see which shift time frame it is in, then increments the count for that time frame. Logical, works, but definitely not efficient.

EDIT:

[Example of OR data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydVMW.png)

[Example of df data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCWkP.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: In your case please provide an example DataFrame (`OR.head()`) and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without example data, it's not absolutely clear what you want. But this should help you vectorise:

```
numSurgeries = {shift: np.sum((OR['PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM'] >= df.DateTime[shift]) & \
                       (OR['PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM'] < df.DateTime[shift+1])) \
                       for shift in range(len(df.Date))}
```

The output is a dictionary mapping integer shift to numSurgeries.

Comment: Thank you! I have also attached example data as pictures in the edit

Comment: @CharlesBushrow, OK, the main thing you need to make sure is columns are appropriately type-casted in pandas, otherwise the comparison operations won't work.

Comment: Great! Yeah with this setup it's flying now

Comment: @CharlesBushrow, excellent - do accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it is hard to answer without example data.

However, a boolean mask sounds fitting. See [Select dataframe rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates).

Create a date mask from `shift`, we'll call the start and end dates `start_shift` and `end_shift` respectively. These should be in `datetime` format.

```
date_mask = (df['datetime'] >= start_shift) & (df['datetime'] <= end_shift)
```

Locate all values in `df` that fit this range.

```
df_shift = df.loc[date_mask]
```

Count the number of instances in the new `df_shift`.

```
num_surgeries = len(df_shift.index())
```

Cycle through all shifts.

```
def count_shifts(df, shift, results_df, start_shift, end_shift):

    date_mask = (df['datetime'] >= start_shift) & (df['datetime'] <= end_shift)
    df_shift = df.loc[date_mask]
    num_surgeries = len(df_shift.index())

    return(num_surgeries)

# iterates through df and applies the above function to every row
results_df['num_surgeries'] = results_df.apply(calculate_num_surgeries,axis=1)
```

Also remember to name variables according to [PEP8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)! Camelcase is not recommended in Python.

Comment: That makes sense! I attached example data as pictures in the edit