# How to select a specific date range in a csv file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am new to Python playing around with a csv file. I would like to find a way to print out my graph by selecting a specific date range, for example *2013-03-20:2014-03-04.*

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prc=pd.read_csv("csv",parse_dates=True, nrows=150, usecols=["Close"])

prc_ma=prc.rolling(5).mean()


plt.plot(prc, color="blue", label="Price")
plt.plot(prc_ma, color="red", label="Moving Average")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("Moving Average")
plt.grid()
```

I currently work with the parameter nrows.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select dataframe rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter for the dates with `.loc` assuming datetimes are the index of dataframe:

```
prc = pd.read_csv("csv", parse_dates=True, nrows=150, usecols=["Close"])

prc_sub = prc.loc['2013-03-20':'2014-03-04']
```

To demonstrate with random data subsetted out of all days of 2013 and 2014:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
np.random.seed(1001)

prc = pd.DataFrame({'PRICE': abs(np.random.randn(730))}, 
                    index=pd.date_range("2013-01-01", "2014-12-31", freq="D"))

# SUBSETTED DATAFRAME
prc_sub = prc.loc['2013-03-20':'2014-03-04']

prc_ma = prc_sub.rolling(5).mean()

plt.plot(prc_sub, color="blue", label="Price")
plt.plot(prc_ma, color="red", label="Moving Average")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("Moving Average")
plt.grid()
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Perfect use of loc! I would probably have created a mask with `m = prc.index.to_series().between('2013-03-20','2014-03-04')`. But this is more readable!

Comment: @AntonvBR ... Indeed, if dates is not an index, boolean indexing with a mask would be needed. Let's await OP's confirmation.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with the .loc attribute. Can there be a problem in the raw data? And do I understand correctly, that the code before # SUBSETTED DATAFRAME is used as an example?

Comment: Please post a few rows of *prc*. To use `.loc` as mentioned in answer, the index of *prc* must be datetime. Does structure resemble the random number example?

Comment: The below part of this answer is a demo of `.loc`. For you as the OP, ignore this section and use your own data. Future readers may find it useful.