# Pandas select date_range with empty rows does not work

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

in a pandas data frame I have a column with dates and empty values like that

```
15    2018-04-13 13:26:54 UTC
16                           
    ...
28                           
29    2018-05-15 00:00:00 UTC
30                           
    ...
40                           
41                           
42    2018-03-24 20:32:36 UTC
    ...
46    2018-04-10 20:41:39 UTC
47                           
48                           
49    2018-01-26 20:30:22 UTC
    ....
58   2017-05-30 09:26:04 UTC
59   2010-09-09 14:09:03 UTC
```

and I am searching for values empty and in a date range. Unfortunately nothing like that worked

```
df[df['date_column'].loc['2017-01-01':'2018-01-01']]
df['date_column']isin(pd.date_range('two_months', periods=2, freq='M'))
df[df['date_column'].str.contains(regex_filters_date)]
```

How would I correctly select dates within a given range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have following data frame

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-03-24 20:32:36 UTC','','2018-01-26 20:30:22 UTC','']})
s=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df[(s>pd.to_datetime('2018-02-01'))&(s<pd.to_datetime('2018-04-01'))]
                      Date
0  2018-03-24 20:32:36 UTC
```

If you want empty selected

```
df[((s > pd.to_datetime('2018-02-01')) & (s < pd.to_datetime('2018-04-01')))|s.isnull()]
Out[831]: 
                      Date
0  2018-03-24 20:32:36 UTC
1                         
3
```

Comment: that does purge the empty values but works fine with the date range

Comment: @user3732793 yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method of specifying a date range in pandas is to use a Boolean Mask, however there are other methods using tools such as the DatetimeIndex class.

[Here is some documentation from an earlier thread I think you would find useful!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Using a boolean mask, your solution would look something like:

```
mask = (df['date_column'] > '2017-01-01') & (df['date_column'] <= '2018-01-01')
df = df.loc[[mask]]
```

Comment: looks promising but gives me back "too many values to unpack" for the column and nothing for the whole df, thanks for the link