# Most efficient way in Pandas to assign tuples to segments

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the following piece of code which assigns tuples to segments. A segment is a container of tuples and spans a certain time interval. Contrary to a tuple which has just 1 timestamp.

However, since my code has ~ 30 000 tuples, and this step is iterated quite often, it spends a lot of time on this method.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

```
for timestamp, tuple in tuples.iterrows():
    this_seg = [s for s in segments if s.can_have(timestamp)]
    assert(len(this_seg) <= 1)
    for s in this_seg:
        s.append(tuple)
return segments
```

Here is some more context:

A *segment* is a class of type Segment, and has a constructor as follows:

```
def __init__(self, ts_max, ts_min):
            self._df = pd.DataFrame({})
            self._ts_max = ts_max
            self._ts_min = ts_min
```

The method can_have checks whether the given timestamp, could be part of the segment: i.e. timestamp lies between ts_min and ts_max.

*Tuples* is a Pandas dataframe, which has timestamps as indices and some other features as columns.

Comment: What's a segment? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Same here, what is `segments` what is `can_have` , why is it applied on the index and not the value ? the code is really unclear

Comment: @UriGoren I have updated my question with some more context. Please tell me if not clear.

Comment: @TomVerstraete, Looks like you have a class. Take the time to create a **minimal** and **self-contained** example. Your code doesn't run for any of us trying to replicate your issue.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using classes to iterate on date intervals. If you post a sample of your data and your desired output, I can help you further. I can recommend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates) and `searchsorted` method (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html)) for something that is way faster than your lookup. `searchsorted` should work in your case, since given your `assert` statement, date intervals are disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterrows is the slowest way to do things in Pandas. It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do, but this tutorial offers several faster replacements for iterrows.

https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/