# Select DataFrame row by time range

Tags: python, pandas

I need to select the rows +- 1sec from specific lines (marked as to_pick)

I can do it with loops, but I looking for more elegant way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 1000
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-07-01 09:30:00', periods=N, freq='S')
np.random.seed(3)
data = np.random.randn(N)
ts = tidx + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.random.randn(N), unit='s')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ts, 'to_pick': pd.np.random.randn(N) > 0.98, 'start': ts - pd.to_timedelta(1, 's'), 'end': ts + pd.to_timedelta(1, 's')})
df.loc[~df['to_pick'], 'start'] = pd.np.nan
df.loc[~df['to_pick'], 'end'] = pd.np.nan
```

I am looking for something like

```
 df['Time'].between(df['start', df['end'])
```

that will work to combine the conditions

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates

Comment: what is df[start] and df[end]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select rows whose `Time` are between `start` and `end` when `to_pick = true`:

```
start = df.query('to_pick')['start'].values
end = df.query('to_pick')['end'].values
t = df['Time'].values[:, None]

df.loc[np.any((start <= t) & (t <= end), axis=1)]
```

Comment: this is great! I need to understand how these line works 
    t = df['Time'].values[:, None]  
    (start <= t)

Comment: It's using numpy array broadcast. Let me know if you want me to elaborate