# Pandas DataFrame: multiply values in a column, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Hi I have a DataFrame column like the follow.

dataframe['BETA'], which has float numbers between 0 and 100. 
I need to have just numbers with the same numbers of digits. Example:

```
Dataframe['BETA´]:

[0] 0.11 to [0] 110
[1] 1.54 to [1] 154
[2] 22.1 to [2] 221
```

I tried to change one by one, but its super inefficient process:

```
for i in range (len(df_ld)):
    nbeta=df_ld['BETA'][i]
    if nbeta<1:
        val=nbeta
        val=val*1000
        df_ld.loc[i,'BETA']=val
    if (nbeta>=1) and (nbeta<=10):
        val=nbeta
        val=val*100
        df_ld.loc[i,'BETA']=val

    if (nbeta>10) and (nbeta<=100):
        val=nbeta
        val=val*10
        df_ld.loc[i,'BETA']=val
        #print('%.f >10, %.f Nuevo valor'% (nbeta,val))
```

Note: The dataframe size is more then 80k elements

Please help!

**Edited: Solution
numpy.select**

```
import numpy as np
x = df_ld['BETA']
condlist = [x<1, (x>=1) & (x<10),(x>=10) & (x<100)]
choicelist = [x*1000, x*100,x*10]
output=np.select(condlist, choicelist)
df_ld.insert(4,'BETA3',output,True)
```

Thank you!

Comment: always use inlines with pandas if you want efficiency...

Comment: I'd use `log10`, assuming 0 < Beta <= 100.. `s = (np.log10(df.Beta)//1)*-1+2; (df.Beta*(10**s)).astype(int)`

Comment: Another approach is to use `.loc` to mask out the range you need to multiply and perform 3 multiplications. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I'm guessing your dataframe is called `df_ld` and your target column is `df_ld['BETA']`.

```
def multiply(column):
    newcol = []
    for item in column:
        if item<1:
            item=item*1000
            newcol.append(item)
        if (item>=1) and (item<=10):
            item=item*100
            newcol.append(item)
        if (item>10) and (item<=100):
            item=item*10
            newcol.append(item)
    return newcol

# apply function and create new column 
df_ld['newcol'] = multiply(df_ld['BETA'])
```