# How to check a date column falls in a specific month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm processing a file which has a date coulmn. I want to check that file contains records for the last month's all days.

That is, if I process the September file,
I would like to know which contain rows for September 1st -September 30th.
Check data of the previous month. Not for current month.
How can I do this in Pandas?

```
    def is_delivery_ready_to_process():

        dateCols = ['Document Date']
        data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_path, f), parse_dates=dateCols,
                                   dayfirst=True, sheet_name='Refined')
.....?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get the start date and end date of previous month

1. find today.
2. use that to find the first day of this month.
3. use `timedelta` to get the last day of the previous month.
4. use `replace(day=1)` to get first day of the previous month

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
previous_month_end = today.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
previous_month_start = previous_month_end.replace(day=1)
print(previous_month_start) # 2019-09-01
print(previous_month_end) # 2019-09-30
```

Next, select dataframe rows between 2 dates using a [boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370182/2970853), for example

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Document Date'],
                  data=[datetime.date(2019, 10, 1),
                        datetime.date(2019, 9, 1),
                        datetime.date(2019, 9, 3)])

df.loc[(df['Document Date'] >= previous_month_start) & (df['Document Date'] <= previous_month_end)]
```

gives you

```
  Document Date
1    2019-09-01
2    2019-09-03
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to filter rows that are within a specific month?

First convert your date string to a datetime object and then do the filtering:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


d = {'date': ["Sep 1 2005", "Sep 1 2005", "Nov 1 2005", "Dec 1 2005", "Apr 1 2005",  "Aug 1 2005", "Aug 1 2005"], 'group': ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"], "value": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data= d)
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %Y')

startdate = datetime(2005, 9, 1)
enddate = datetime(2005, 10, 1)

df[(df.datetime >= startdate) & (df.datetime < enddate)]
```

Output:

```
   date       group value   datetime
0   Sep 1 2005  A   5   2005-09-01
1   Sep 1 2005  A   6   2005-09-01
```