# Is it possible to do pandas DataFrame indexing via pd.Interval?

Tags: python, pandas

I know you typically select parts of a pd.DataFrame with a [boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370182/4292396) or via the `:` operator. I was wondering whether it is possible to do indexing into a pd.DataFrame using a pd.Interval, i.e. I want to accomplish:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c','d','e']})  # df has simple RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
interval = pd.Interval(left=1, right=3, closed='both')

print(df[interval])  # I want items 'b','c','d', but get KeyError
```

So instead I have to go with the more verbose

```
print(df[interval.left: interval.right])
```

Indexing via a defined start- and end-point seems like a feature that *should* be existing, but can't find in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically want `pd.Interval` for this behavior? In your existing example, you could just do something like `df.loc[range(1, 4)]`

Comment: In a real-world use case, I'm thinking more of accessing a time series with `DatetimeIndex` and `pd.Interval` with `pd.Timestamp`, in which case the `range` approach would not work as simply.