# Python Dataframe: Get rows between a specified date range/Period?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `df` with two columns `name` and `time`. I want to find the rows between the inputs - `input1` and `input2`

```
input1 = pd.Period('4/21/2020') 
input2 = pd.Period('5/20/2020')
```

df

```
    raw_data = {
        'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','h','i'], 
        'time': ['2020-03-12','2020-03-16','2020-04-29','2020-03-16',
                 '2020-03-16','2020-04-16','2020-03-09','2020-05-19','2020-04-23']
   } 

    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['name', 'time'])


           name        time
    0       a         2020-03-12
    1       b         2020-03-16
    2       c         2020-04-29
    3       d         2020-03-16
    4       e         2020-03-16
    5       f         2020-04-16
    6       g         2020-03-09
    7       h         2020-05-19
    8       i         2020-04-23
```

My expected output:

df

```
           name        time
    2       c         2020-04-29
    7       h         2020-05-19
    8       i         2020-04-23
```

What i have tried:

```
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
    df = df[df['time'].dt.to_period('d').isin([input1, input2])]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Comment: I'm a bit unsure why you use Period here, but it would work the same way than with dates like in the link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input values are Periods which need to be converted to timestamp,

```
df.loc[(df['time'] > input1.to_timestamp()) & (df['time'] < input2.to_timestamp())]



   name time
2   c   2020-04-29
7   h   2020-05-19
8   i   2020-04-23
```