# searching for records between two dates and two times in csv file using python programming

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having a csv file which is having a lot of entries (rows). The first column contains dates in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, the second one contains time in the format `hh:min:sec`.

All I want is that I will provide the start date, start time, end date, end time and all the records (rows) will be listed between these parameters from the csv file...

I tried using pandas but didnt get any solution.

[image: i am attaching an image of my csv file]

The entries of csv files are as follows:

> ```
> Date      Time     Mode   Dir Reserved    Speed   Enf Speed
> 1/1/2020  0:00:10     N   R   170          103    70
> 1/1/2020  0:00:20     N   R   170           70    70
> 1/1/2020  0:00:30     N   R   170          105    70
> 1/1/2020  0:00:40     N   R   170          115    70
> 1/1/2020  0:00:50     N   R   170           81    70
> 1/1/2020  0:10:00     N   R   170          127    70
> 1/1/2020  0:10:10     N   R   170           74    70
> 1/1/2020  0:10:20     N   R   170          108    70
> ```

Please help me out in how to get data between these date and times..

Thank you.

Comment: if i provide 1/1/2020 0:00:10 to 1/1/2020 0:00:30 then first three records must be fetched..

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the **text** form, not as a picture.

Comment: Corrected, sir.

Comment: @MarianD thank you so much sir..can you help out with my issue?

Comment: Maybe. But you have to provide an example — at least a schematic one — of your desired output in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("Path_to_your_input_dataset")  #Specify your dataset input path here

#Create a new column "DateTime" which concatenates "Date" and "Time" columns and converts the column to pandas DateTime format
dataset['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date '] + ' ' + dataset['Time'])

start_date = "2020-01-01 00:00:40" #Provide your start dateTime as input here in the same exact format
end_date = "2020-01-01 00:10:10" #Provide your end dateTime as input here in the same exact format

#greater than the start date and smaller than the end date
mask = (dataset['DateTime'] >= start_date) & (dataset['DateTime'] <= end_date)

#Assign the selected mask to a new dataframe
selected_dataset = dataset.loc[mask]
print(selected_dataset)
```

**Output:**

```
      Date      Time Mode Dir  Reserved  Speed  Enf Speed            DateTime
3  01/01/20  0:00:40    N   R       170    115         70 2020-01-01 00:00:40
4  01/01/20  0:00:50    N   R       170     81         70 2020-01-01 00:00:50
5  01/01/20  0:10:00    N   R       170    127         70 2020-01-01 00:10:00
6  01/01/20  0:10:10    N   R       170     74         70 2020-01-01 00:10:10
```

Cheers!

Comment: one more thing sir i want to sum Speed column..i am trying using print(selected_dataset.groupby['Speed'].sum()) but i am getting error TypeError:Method 'object' is not subscriptable..plz help me in this also

Comment: ```print(selected_dataset['Speed'].sum())```