# Select Dataset rows between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataset:

[image: dataset]

And want to convert my dataset between two dates. I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29370057/13331547). But it didn't work.

Here is a screenshot using:

Boolean Mask[image: Boolean Mask]

and 
DatetimeIndex
[image: DatetimeIndex]

Comment: Looks like your data after filter doesn't have 100 rows, while `pd.date_range(..., periods=100, freq='D')` does.

Comment: I edited the screenshot, please see again!

Comment: what do you mean by "it didn't work"?  the boolean mask screen shot seems to show only rows with dates in between the specified start and end date (aka it looks like it worked)

Comment: It should have shown data from 2020-03-25 rather than 2020-04-02

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images. It would help if you copy and pasted the error messages too. See [how to make reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate the scenario shared by you with the same data.
While exploring the results, I observed that the data is not in sorted format.

Try to run `sort_values('Date')` on your result.

`data[(data['Date'] >= '2020-03-25') & (data['Date'] <= '2020-05-22')].sort_values('Date')`

[image]

You will get above result.