# How to resolve abnormal summation of data and missing date in dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I selected the date range for my dataset using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221921/select-dataset-rows-between-two-dates). But now there seems to be an abnormality in my data when I use pandas groupby and sum, there seems to be missing data.

*The date b/w 2020-04-07 to 2020-04-12 is missing and those date data are being added to 2020-04-06*

**Code**:

```
covid19India['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid19India['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
covid19India_new= covid19India[(covid19India['Date'] >= '2020-03-25') & (covid19India['Date']  <= '2020-05-31')].sort_values('Date')
```

```
df1=covid19India_new.groupby('Date').sum()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```
df1.head(20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can drop rows with missing values from your dataframe before applying the groupby() and sum().

```
covid19India['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid19India['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
# drop any rows with at least one missing value
covid19India_new= covid19India[(covid19India['Date'] >= '2020-03-25') & (covid19India['Date']  <= '2020-05-31')].sort_values('Date').dropna()
df1=covid19India_new.groupby('Date').sum()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: There are no missing values data for date between 2020-04-07 to 2020-04-13 is present but it's being merged in 2020-04-06

Comment: That's strange... I'll see if i can figure out an alternate solution

Comment: I made changes and it worked but I'm not able to understand what's the issue was, can you explain?


covid19India['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid19India['Date'], ̶i̶n̶f̶e̶r̶_̶d̶a̶t̶e̶t̶i̶m̶e̶_̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶=̶T̶r̶u̶e̶ dayfirst=True)

and

df1=covid19India_new.groupby( ̶'̶D̶a̶t̶e̶'̶covid19India_new['Date']).sum()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1=df1.drop('Sno',axis=1)