# How to select rows based on range date column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create new data frame that select rows that has range date from df['Date'] column between 2020-01-01 to 2020-03-31 in pandas python from below data frame. Anyone can help me?

```
  Date        Name      Status
0 2020-01-01  Ali       Closed
1 2020-01-05  Sara      Closed
2 2020-02-15  Tyra      Approve
3 2020-03-19  Alia      Reject
4 2020-03-29  Aiman     Closed
5 2020-05-01  Alice     Closed
6 2020-07-12  Danish    Closed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to select rows based on a condition.

```
mask = (df['Date'] >= '2020-01-01') & (df['Date'] <= '2020-03-31')
q1_df = df[mask]
```

Comment: You got twice as much rep as me, how about taking 5 seconds to check for a duplicate? :)