# Finding the mean of a data column for a specified date-time range in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mean

New to this forum and to coding in general, so I apologize if this is a repeat question, will delete if so!

I'm currently working with pandas in python and attempting to find a mean value within one of my data frame columns.

I've created my dataframe, and called it 'data':   `data=pd.DataFrame()`.

The first column is a date-time column and I've set it up as follows, converting it to date-time:

`data.iloc[:,0]= pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:,0], format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") #yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`

I've been able to find the mean for an entire column using the .mean() function for my data column of interest:

`data["new6"].mean()`

However, I'm trying to find the mean for this column but only for a specific date-time range (and the date-time data is in a different column).

Is this possible to do?

Another option is to create a smaller dataframe as a subset of the current dataframe. Here I've named the new dataframe 'data_d.t.specified', and would only include columns within the date-time range desired.

`data_d.t.specified = data.drop(data[(0 >= index value here) | 0 <= index value here])`

I've tried this using a date-time format but I've had issues with using strings here, so opted for using the index value of the date-time of interest. However, I can't seem to find out the index value for the specific date-time that I want.
I've been using the following code, where the date-time column is column 0, but the only thing that it prints is `[]` .

`print(data[data[0]=="20/08/23 13:05:02"].index.values)`

Is this an issue with what I'm calling the date-time column? Or have I not converted it to date-time properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try converting your single string in the `==` comparison to a `Datetime` object. Also, I highly recommend reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Since you made it a datetime column you can easily use `.loc` to focus on a date range:

```
df.loc[(df['Dates'] >= datetime(2020, 7, 21) & df['Dates'] <= datetime(2021, 1, 14)), 'col_to_mean'].mean()
```

where:

- `'Dates'` is the name of the column with the dates to `.loc` on
- `datetime(2020, 7, 21)` is a date you want to split on in Year, Month, Day format. You can add time easily. See datetime [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).
- `'col_to_mean'` is the name of the column you want the mean of

Just adjust the logic to be whatever date range you want