# Selecting some rows from a column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with dates in the index and the name of some product as columns titles.

In order to do some calculations I want to get the data from a column but only from one date to another. I know how to get a single row or column from a dataframe but how to get this kind of subset. I attach an image of the DataFrame to make it more visual.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Comment: You can you loc and iloc methods for that.
You can find more about it from the below link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label