# How to extract rows from CSV file based on parameters (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-extraction

I'm very very new to coding so I apologize if my questioning format is incorrect. I'm pretty sure my problem is simple, I'm just not sure how to approach it.

I have a CSV file called SouthKoreaRoads2, and I used the following code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
SouthKoreaRoads2 = pd.read_csv("SouthKoreaRoads2.csv")
```

[image: This is what my CSV file looks like]

As you can see, there are dates in the second column. I need to extract the rows with dates under 1975. How should I proceed with this? Many thanks in advance, and any and all suggestions are very welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

filter your data frame by date column.

```
df = SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['DateColumn'] < 1975]
```

or

```
df = SouthKoreaRoads2.query('DateColumn< 1975')
```

assuming that the column is named `DateColumn`

Comment: My column is called Simplified Date, and I did df = SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]     but he response was a name error that SouthKoreaRoads2 is not defined. What would u recommend?

Comment: your code example shows that the dataframe is called `SouthKoreaRoads2`, unless you changed it, this should work

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2[1] < 1975]
```

the `1` in `SouthKoreaRoads2[1]` takes your second column, if you have a column name associated just replace with `SouthKoreaRoads2['the column name']`

or if you like working with, let's say, the coordinates you can use this one as well:

```
SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2.iloc[:, 1] < 1975]
```

`iloc[:, 1]` - takes all the rows of the second column

Comment: Wow, thank you SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]
worked perfectly. One more follow-up question, if I wanted to now extract the ones between 1975 and 1990, how would I set up that?

Comment: @Bopy either you can do just double filtering, firstly >1975 after <1990 or for a more advanced way you can refer the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates

Comment: Double filtering was a really helpful suggestion, thank you!