# Pandas date index loc between dates throws KeyError when edge date is not in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I can't understand why I'm getting KeyError: Timestamp('...') when using loc on date index.

With given df: `dtypes are datetime64[ns], int, int`, **`DATE1 is index`**

```
            DATE1    VALUE2  VALUE3
2021-08-20 00:00:00      11     424
2021-08-21 00:00:00      22     424
2021-08-22 00:00:00      33     424
2021-08-23 00:00:00      44     242
```

I'm trying to use loc on index like this:

```
start_date = date(2021-08-20)
end_date = date(2021-08-23)
df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

and this is working fine. I'm getting 4 records. **However** when I do this:

```
start_date = date(2021-08-20)
end_date = date(2021-08-24) #end_date is higher than values in dataframe
df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

I'm getting KeyError: `KeyError: Timestamp('2021-08-24 00:00:00')`. Could someone point me how to resolve this?

Comment: I tried it and is not reproducible. Can you use `pd.to_datetime` to convert start and end date strings to datetime then use `.loc`

Comment: what is `date(2021-08-20)`? You can also try `df.between(start_date, end_date)` instead.

Comment: @HenryYik it's datetime.date(2021-08-20). For between I'm getting 'DatetimeIndex object has no attribute between'.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use label-based slices with bounds outside of index range, the index must be monotonically increasing or decreasing.

From [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#non-monotonic-indexes-require-exact-matches):

> If the index of a Series or DataFrame is monotonically increasing or decreasing, then the bounds of a label-based slice can be outside the range of the index, much like slice indexing a normal Python list. Monotonicity of an index can be tested with the is_monotonic_increasing() and is_monotonic_decreasing() attributes.
>
> On the other hand, if the index is not monotonic, then both slice bounds must be unique members of the index.

You can use [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html?highlight=sort_index#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) to sort the index and then out of bounds slices should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a max to cap the last date in the data:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = """DATE1|VALUE2|VALUE3
2021-08-20 00:00:00    |  11    | 424
2021-08-21 00:00:00    |  22   |  424
2021-08-22 00:00:00    |  33   |  424
2021-08-23 00:00:00    |  44  |   242"""

def str_to_date(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s.strip(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), sep='|')
df['DATE1'] = df['DATE1'].apply(lambda s: str_to_date(s))
df = df.set_index('DATE1')
```

Then:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime('2021-08-20', "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = min(datetime.strptime('2021-08-24', "%Y-%m-%d"), max(df.index))

df3 = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

[out]:

```
    VALUE2  VALUE3
DATE1       
2021-08-20  11  424
2021-08-21  22  424
2021-08-22  33  424
2021-08-23  44  242
```

The line `min(datetime.strptime('2021-08-24', "%Y-%m-%d"), max(df.index)` does:

- `max_date = max(df.index)` stores the latest date
- `min(end_date, max_date)` takes the nearest/lower date

Comment: This feels like a hack. Why can't I just put date which is beyond max(df.index) in loc?

Comment: Because loc isn't smart enough to do a max on the column (unfortunately). Loc is looking for the index and it's a simple dictionary where the key isn't found when you try to set a date higher than anything between the range.

Comment: Similar issues reported in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341066/610569

Answer (score 0):

Which pandas version are you using? It works fine for me:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-08-20')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2121-08-24')
df.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

output:

```
            VALUE2  VALUE3
DATE1                     
2021-08-20      11     424
2021-08-21      22     424
2021-08-22      33     424
2021-08-23      44     242
```