# Python using "if" in Datetime Index

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a pd like below:

"Date" is the index, not column

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 3 |
| 2020-01-04 | 4 |
| 2020-01-05 | 5 |

and I want to do something like
if date > 2020-01-02 and date < 2020-01-05

then Value = 0

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 2020-01-05 | 5 |

.loc can only trim the whole data set and I don't want that.
May I know what can I do to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: What is pd and what is .loc?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

In case it could be useful, here's an option using `df.loc`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Value'].loc[(df['Date'] > "2020-01-02") & (df['Date'] < "2020-01-05")] = 0
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use `.loc` and hasn't specified the type of the datetime column

Comment: Sorry @Luke, I've edited the answer. You need to change the date column to datetime format before filtering

Comment: Hi, Im sorry there is no df['Date'] column, it is a datetime index, not a column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `if...else` Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'],
    'Value': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df['Value'] = [
    0 if (x > '2020-01-02') & (x <= '2020-01-04') else  df['Value'].iloc[idx]
    for idx, x in enumerate(df['Date'])
]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date    Value
0  2020-01-01      1
1  2020-01-02      2
2  2020-01-03      0
3  2020-01-04      0
4  2020-01-05      5
```

Or  you can use `.loc` like below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'],
    'Value': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  
df.loc[(df['Date'] > '2020-01-02') & (df['Date'] <= '2020-01-04'), 'Value'] = 0
```

**Edit Base On Your Comment (if Date is index):**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'],
    'Value': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

[image]

For the above DataFrame you can use `df.reset_index()` and like below:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  
df.loc[(df['Date'] > '2020-01-02') & (df['Date'] <= '2020-01-04'), 'Value'] = 0
```

With `if...else`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Value'] = [
    0 if (x > '2020-01-02') & (x <= '2020-01-04') else  df['Value'].iloc[idx]
    for idx, x in enumerate(df['Date'])
]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry the "Date" is the index, not the column. so I think I cannot use the method as you.

Comment: @user3239756 edited answer , for this problem you can use `df.reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks I will try to use reset_index(), however, can I use if statement with it? I actually want to do a series of functions/validation more than just put a value.

Comment: @user3239756 edited answer again and add part `if..else` in the end of answer

Comment: Thanks, I got this error  :  '>' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str' but I think the reset index is the first start

Comment: @user3239756 if you write :`for idx, x in enumerate(df['Date']) : if (x > '2020-01-02')` don't write `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` because in `if` you check `string` with `df['Date']` and you need data in `df['Date']` will be `string`