# Python: Dataframe starting from specific date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, pandas-loc

Using python, how can I take the values from 2021-09-13 to 2021-09-16?

I tried the following:

```
date_start = df['date'].iloc[-4] #2021-09-13
date_end = df['date'].iloc[-1] #2021-09-16
df = df.loc[date_start:date_end]
```

but it returns only the rows for 2021-09-13 and 2021-09-16

| index | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-09 | 2021-09-09 | 10 |
| 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-10 | 20 |
| 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 30 |
| 2021-09-14 | 2021-09-14 | 40 |
| 2021-09-15 | 2021-09-15 | 50 |
| 2021-09-16 | 2021-09-16 | 60 |

Desired outcome:

| index | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 30 |
| 2021-09-14 | 2021-09-14 | 40 |
| 2021-09-15 | 2021-09-15 | 50 |
| 2021-09-16 | 2021-09-16 | 60 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,1)))
df['index'] = pd.date_range('2021-9-1', periods=200, freq='D')
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2021-9-1', periods=200, freq='D')
mask = (df['date'] >= '2021-9-13') & (df['date'] <= '2021-9-16')
print(df.loc[mask])
```

**Output:**

```
           0      index       date
12  0.936342 2021-09-13 2021-09-13
13  0.357040 2021-09-14 2021-09-14
14  0.776492 2021-09-15 2021-09-15
15  0.543956 2021-09-16 2021-09-16
```