# python pandas | double conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

| volume | price | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00 |
| 300 | 2 | 2021-09-29 04:30:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 5 | 2021-09-29 05:30:00-04:00 |
| 500 | 9 | 2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 22 | 2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00 |
| 400 | 1 | 2021-09-29 07:00:00-04:00 |

Return the `price` with the highest `volume`.  if there are 2 `volume` that are same, then return the lower `price` ( it is 5 in this case)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to use two conditionals at once, or obtain one result and then reduce it further?

Comment: either works.  i only know   df['volume].max() to return the max value.  the logic should be " if there 2 or even more occurence of the max volume (for example there are 3 rows that has the volume 900), then return the lowest price out of these 3 row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. First, find the row(s) that have the max volume (I left out the `datetime` column in these examples):

```
>>> df[df.volume == df.volume.max()]
   volume  price
2     900      5
4     900     22
```

Then use that result to find the lowest price:

```
>>> df[df.volume == df.volume.max()].price.min()
5
```

Comment: thanks a lot! sorry  actually, do you mind advise on one more filter. on top of that  if i want to say within certain time frame, find out the max volume,  if there are more than 1 max volume, find the mind price. so basically  i am thinking adding .between but not sure  how to nest it in the function given by you above

Comment: @GinSnipe: It might be best to open another question for that. There's some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates) that may help.