# How to select specific rows based on their date values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
##    No - V - Date   
 -  55375 X 2020-01-23   
 -  55376 X 2020-01-24   
 -  ....           
 -  56065 X 2021-12-13   
 -  56066 X 2021-12-14
```

And I want data in a specific time range like only from 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-01.
I'm kinda new to python and pandas so i couldn't figure it out how to trim the rest fo the data.

Comment: Please format your dataframe properly. @Sei

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802199/16267793

Comment: is this a single column "No - V - Date"?

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

```
# Importing dependencies 
import pandas as pd 
import datetime

# Reading in data
df = pd.read_csv('test2.txt')
df

# Splitting the column into different columns
df[['No','V','Date']] = df['No - V - Date'].str.split(' ',expand=True)

# Converting date column to correct datatype
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
```

**Time Range**

```
# Time range, you would reset this for the range of dates you want 
recent_date = datetime.date(2021, 12, 1)
older_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)

# Conditions to look at dates that are within 9 years from today
df = df[(df.Date <= recent_date) & (df.Date >= older_date)]

# Viewing dataframe 
df
```

**Output**

```
    No - V - Date        No     V      Date
0   55375 X 2020-01-23  55375   X   2020-01-23
1   55376 X 2020-01-24  55376   X   2020-01-24
```