# Creating a time series with multiple columns and extracting subset between dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have below data in `Python`

```
import pandas as pd

var1 = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4])
var2 = pd.DataFrame([6,7,8,9,10])
var = pd.concat([var1 , var2], axis = 1)
days = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=5, freq="D")
```

Now I want to create a time series for `var` with index `days` and then extract subset of `var` that falls between `'2018-01-02'` & `'2018-01-04'`

Is there any way to achieve this using `pandas`?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: @smci if you like you can adding your thought in that post ~

Comment: See [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates) pandas has [`DataFrame.truncate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html) for selecting by date-index between certain dates. (Make your index a pd.Timestamp , pandas has lots of helpful date/datetime-aware functions, gets the sort order right, handles intervals etc. etc.) (Yes you could use a simple string index instead of a proper Timestamp, but it's worse for all sorts of reasons).