# can't use | nor and when comparing datetimes in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a simple problem : I have a Dataframe containing some data, read from a csv file. I need to create a new DataFrame with the entries of the first dataframe where the field 'date' is contained between the two parameters startDate and endDate.

This works when i only put one parameter (<= endDate or >= startDate for example) BUT : using | to use both conditions returns : "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'str'"
and using "and" does not work since I am working with a DataFrame. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import to_datetime
import datetime
def data_cleaning_part(startDate, endDate):
    path = "./sessions.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    filteredsessions = df[(pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) <= endDate) | (df[pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) >=startDate])]
    filteredsessions.to_csv("filteredsessions.csv")
    return filteredsessions
```

Comment: Use `&`, not `|` to make it between.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates this answers my question. sorry for asking.