# The right way to parse date

Tags: python, date, datetime, timedelta

Exist an easier way to do this kind of parse date?

I'm trying to make a filter in pandas to localize dates 3 months ago and loc the entire month too.

The code works, but I'm searching for the best way.

```
final_date = pd.to_datetime(f'{(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=90)).year}-{(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=90)).month}-01', dayfirst=True)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/29370057/10197418 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### My Suggestion

This version of the code is more concise and easier to read.
It avoids using multiple calls to datetime.today() and string formatting.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Calculate the date 90 days ago
d = date.today() - timedelta(days=90)

# Format the date as a string in the '%Y-%m-01' format
date_str = d.strftime('%Y-%m-01')

# Parse the string as a datetime object
final_date = pd.to_datetime(date_str, dayfirst=True)
```

Comment: It might be simpler to bypass the roundtrip through a `str` and use `pd.to_datetime(d.replace(day=1), dayfirst=True)`.